# How is the solution of an ODE identically zero?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analytic-functions, smooth-functions, sturm-liouville

I am reading Sturmian theory on Edward Ince's classic *Ordinary Differential Equation* and I again come across the statement that's been baffling me:

*Consider $\frac{d}{dx}\left(K\frac{dy}{dx}\right)-Gy=0$ with $K>0$ and $G$ both being continuous on the interval $a\leq x\leq b$, and let $c\in[a, b]$. Then the initial value problem with initial values $y(c)=y'(c)=0$ has no solution not identically zero.* (Page 224.)

I don't see why the initial values would imply that the solution is identically zero. What I can conclude from the information at hand is the fact that $y(c)=y'(c)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(K\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\bigg\rvert_{x=c}=0$, which, if $K$ is a nonzero constant, also means that $y''(c)=0$. Continued differentiation of the differential equation also shows that $y^{(n)}(c)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. But how can we conclude that $y$ is identically zero?

I am aware that there are works of literature out there that say that $y$ is identical zero because the Taylor series around $x=c$ is $0$. But this can't be true unless we know that the Taylor series exists and is convergent at $x=c$ and even that is not enough as we will need solutions $y$ to the differential equation to be always analytic (which I doubt so); it is even not enough to assume that the solution is smooth ($C^\infty([a, b])$).

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a unique solution $y$ given the requirement that $y(c)=A$, $y'(c)=B$. This is because the ODE is a regular second-order linear ODE on $[a,b]$.

Comment: Yes, I am clear about that, but how does that imply that the solution y is identically zero?

Comment: @BenjaminT If $y(c)=y'(c)=0$, then $y\equiv 0$ because $0$ is a solution, and the solution is unique.

Comment: Owh now that is obvious! Thanks!